# How to render component from loading after axios request

Tags: vue.js, axios

In script of my Component , I make a get request with axios but the component is rendered before the result of request is ready. How can I do it?
By the way I tried onBeforeMount and putting axios.get in a sync function and calling it inside onMounted and these does not work.

```js
<template>
    <div class="p-4 m-4 bg-white rounded flex flex-col">
        <div>
            <h1 class="text-2xl text-gray-700">Projects</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="justify-center flex">
            <table class="table-auto justify-center">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="border px-4 py-2">ID</th>
                        <th class="border px-4 py-2">Name</th>
                        <th class="border px-4 py-2">Tasks</th>
                        <th class="border px-4 py-2">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="project in projects" :key="project.id">
                        <td>{{project.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{project.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{project.task_count}}</td>
                        <td>Actions</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script setup>
    import {onMounted , ref} from 'vue';
    let projects = ref(null);

    onMounted(  ()=> {
        axios.get('/api/projects').then(res => {
            projects = res.data.data;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Vue version is relevant. In 3, you can use suspense. Otherwise you need to do the request outside a component and use v-if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only problem is, that you are trying to update ref object directly, but you should update it's inner property *value*, instead...

try to replace this:

```
projects = res.data.data;
```

with this:

```
projects.value = res.data.data;
```

Documentation: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref

If you want the component to be displayed only once *projects* are available (not null), you can add v-if to the root element:

```
<div
  v-if="projects"
  class="p-4 m-4 bg-white rounded flex flex-col"
>
  ...
</div>
```

If there might be a case, when response from API is empty array (null, or something similar), you might need to update the condition in *v-if* (e.g. *projects?.length* with [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)), but it really depends, how you want to handle waiting for the response and 'empty' response...

Documentation: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html#v-if

Comment: Thanks you were right and it worked for me